# Access remote JSON file through WebView

Tags: javascript, webview, remote-server

I have prepared HTML/CSS/JS page which reads a simple JSON file from a server using fetch.
It works perfectly.

Then I use Webview in Android Studio to make an app of the page.
It compiles perfectly and on the simulator I can see the data of the remote JSON file.
I suppose this means that everything works OK.

However when I compile and install the APK , the data is not there.

Does anybody suspects why the App installed on the phone does not connect to the server and fetch the JSON file ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out.
https should be used instead of http !